# Hairete kudasai

Tags: grammar

I met the following exercise online in some very introductory tests.

It uses "入れてください".

But, isn't "Please enter", rather "入ってください"？

I probably still need to learn some new imperative forms but I couldn't make out quite what this is (very beginner)

[image: Exercise that mentions "hairete kudasai"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confusing 入{はい}る (to enter) with 入{い}れる (to let/put in). You're probably confused because they use the same  kanji but they are different verbs. There is no imperative form here.

入{はい}る is an intransitive verb. But 入{い}れる is transitive (can take an object), so すずしいかぜを入{い}れてください means "please let in some fresh air".

Comment: `入る is an intransitive verb`  You should probably put furigana for that too, since now the OP might not know if you mean はいる or いる.

Comment: @istrasci Done. I assumed it was clear from the first line but it never hurts to make sure.